# What is the range of X, Y, Z meaurement for accelerometer on mobile phones?

Tags: mobile, accelerometer

I am trying to visualize the values for X,Y,Z coming from mobile phone's accelerometer.

So I need to know the exact range of their values in order to draw graphs.

I have searched and seen many similar questions, but none of them give a clear answer, e.g. +/-3g.
Although I know g is close to 9.8 m/s^2, but 3 times g does not look like close to the values I got from my experiments.

The values I have got so far, it seems that they are all between -40 <= value <= 40.

Yes, I have seen the other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691097/what-is-android-accelerometer-min-and-max-range) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722600/what-are-the-ranges-of-the-accelerator-on-the-iphone)
Also I have noticed that someone said the value could also reach more than 100 on different devices

So do we have a standard range for these values? if yes, what are they?

Comment: What kind of phone is the data from? is it Android or Iphone? According to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion) (Android) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/getting_raw_accelerometer_events)(Iphone), both process accelerometer data differently. Also, the way they do it may change depending API's version on each platform. Try to find more recent documentation for your case.

Comment: hi @pazitos10 thanks for your information. I did see the Android webpage, but did not find out the range, maybe I wasn't paying attention(but I read it twice), or maybe I just did not understand its concept.